# Сортировка двумерного массива по рядам с++

Tags: c++

Есть динамический двумерный массив, нужно в этом массиве отсортировать парные ряды(тоесть 2,4,6...) по возростанию.

Пробовал через пузырьковую сортировку, но видимо делаю что то неправильно. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На скорую руку:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size;)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size;j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
                if (a[i][k] < a[i][k - 1])
                {
                    int tmp = a[i][k];
                    a[i][k] = a[i][k - 1];
                    a[i][k - 1] = tmp;
                }
        }
        i += 2;
    }
```

Вроде правильно должно быть.